# Database for Crossword puzzle

Tags: database, database-design

I want to design a database to store crossword puzzles,
mainly I have 2 tables:
Questions Table, Grid Table,

Questions Table(q_id, question , answer...)
Grids Table (g_id, name, ....)

when I come to relate Questions Table with Grids Table, I am thinking of a good way,

Questions_Grid(q_id, g_id), the pair would be a primary key,

another solution that my boss suggested : Grids Table ( g_id, q_ids, ....)
q_ids store all the ids of the question used in this grid

which one is better? and if you have better options ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your boss's suggestion is to store a list of question ids as a text column in the grid table. If I understand what you're asking and that's really it, the first one is much better, of course, because it's normalized. In your scheme, you can make many useful queries that would be messy or impossible (and slow, if possible) in your boss's scheme.

Answer (score 1):

The first option is better, in that way the schema of your database does not restrict the number of questions per grid. A rule of thumb is that when you have to change the schema to make the application scale you haven't got an optimal schema.

Answer (score 1):

a link table with one tuple pair is more normalized.

```
Question_grid
-------------
q_id
g_id
```

this will allow you to have as many questions as necessary for the grid, and no more.
if you try to hardcode the list, then each grid will need the same number of questions, or will have blanks or something.. no good.

Answer (score 1):

Well the rule is to make a linking table when you have a "one"(grid) on "many"(questions) relationship. So your option would be the best answer, its normalized!